# Microsoft Paint on Windows 10 printout is 5" x 5" but File > Image Properties is just 1.04" x 1.04" image

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-paint

I'm trying to print-out a QR code .bmp file using Windows 10 PAINT.
PAINT > File > Image Properties shows width & height are 1.04 x 1.04 inches.

But when it prints out, it's about 5" x 5".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAINT > File > Print Page Setup >
set Scaling = Adjust to: 100%